# How to make a javascript function with elementid like argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery, devexpress-mvc

I have an DevExpress Mvc token extension, where the user will insert several items.

Using javascript I send the items to the controller, which is working fine.

My function look like this:

```
 $(function() {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        var name = window.ComboBox.GetValue();
        var i;

        var team = new Array();
        var tokens = window.tokenBox.GetTokenCollection();
        for (i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            team.push(tokens[i]);
        }



        var s = new Array();
        var ss = window.tokenBox2.GetTokenCollection();
        for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
            s.push(ss[i]);
        }


        var w = new Array();
        var ww = window.tokenBox3.GetTokenCollection();
        for (i = 0; i < ww.length; i++) {
            w.push(ww[i]);
        }

        var o = new Array();
        var oo = window.tokenBox4.GetTokenCollection();
        for (i = 0; i < oo.length; i++) {
            o.push(oo[i]);
        }

        var t = new Array();
        var tt = window.tokenBox5.GetTokenCollection();
        for (i = 0; i < tt.length; i++) {
            t.push(tt[i]);
        }


        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")',
            data: { name:name, team:team, s:s, o:o, w:w, t:t },
            beforeSend: function () {
                window.loadingPanel.Show();
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $("#mainAjax").html(response);
                window.loadingPanel.Hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I want to use a function, to get the items from token and put them in an array (not repetitive code like above), something like this:

```
function GetTokenItems(token) {
    var list = new Array();
    var el = document.getElementsById(token);
    var tokens = el.GetTokenCollection();
    for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        list.push(tokens[i]);
    }
 return list;
    };
```

This function is not working, error says:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function

How can I pass the Id of the tokenBok like argument in a function, or/and what is wrong with my function?

```
**Edit:**
```

I made the correction `document.getElementById` and now I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: el.GetTokenCollection is not a function

Comment: getElement*s*ById. Typo?

Answer (score 0):

Should be [`document.getElementById(id)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

> Returns a reference to the element by its ID; the ID is a string which can be used to identify the element; it can be established using the id attribute in HTML, or from script.

```
document.getElementById(...)
//                ^ without s
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of my issue, maybe will be helpfull for others!

For Devexpress mvc extensions is enough to use the name of the extension like argument, no need to look for him with `document.getElementById`, so my function is working like this:

```
 function GetTokenItems(token) {
    var list = new Array();

    var tokens = token.GetTokenCollection();
    for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        list.push(tokens[i]);
    }
    return list;
};
```

now I can call this function like this:

`var team=GetTokenItems(tokenBox);` and is working!!!